# MVC4 Membership Tables not created on production environment

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to use the ASP.NET universal providers in my MVC4 application. Among other places, [this article](http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.com/2012/04/membership-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html) describes how, the first time you attempt to register a user, the tables should auto-create in my DB.

I had this working on my internal app/db, but I used the asp.net web configuration tool to create my first user. When I deployed this to production, I attempted to register a user and was hit with an error indicating `dbo.Applications` didn't exist, which is one of the tables that should have been created.

Any thoughts on why these tables weren't created? I've made sure the `System.Web.Providers` dll was copied to the bin folder. I'm also sure my app can manage CRUD tasks on my database.

Comment: argh duh. Turns out I didn't have create perms set up for the app pool identity that was making the call. **Hangs head in shame**

Comment: Feel free to add this as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

argh duh. Turns out I didn't have create perms set up for the app pool identity that was making the call. Hangs head in shame